# What are the reasons for company buyouts, why being a majority stakeholder is not enough?

Tags: shares

Why companies are being bought out/taken over completely, why not becoming of a majority shareholder is not enough?

Why Elon Musk bought the whole Twitter, why he didn't get just 51% share of the voting stock? It would give him the right to do whatever he wanted to do with the company and much cheaper.

Why French state bough whole of EDF, the French energy and utility company, in 2022 when it already controlled over 80% of it?

I assume that taking a company private a lot of pesky reporting requirements no longer apply and company can operate in much opaque manner.

Also some types of restructuralization, like merger or a split would require complete buyout.

Is there anything else?

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that taking a company private a lot of pesky reporting
> requirements no longer apply and company can operate in much opaque
> manner.

When you see that a company has gone private, that is the main reason for doing so. The company doesn't have to be owned by just one person, but the number of people with an ownership stake is small.  Being private doesn't exempt them from filing taxes, but it does exempt them from having to deal with other reporting requirements.

> Also some types of restructuralization, like merger or a split would
> require complete buyout.

A split doesn't require going private, unless the goal is to make the split part private. Lets say that big_company_A is going to split-off splitB because they want to get out of that line of work. They will follow their corporate rules for making that decision. In some cases all the shareholders of big_company_A will get shares of splitB, or big_company_A could decide to sell splitB and every shareholder of big_company_A would receive cash. Or something in between.

Mergers are handled in a similar way. The resulting Superbig_company_A would me made up of the shareholders of both companies. How the shares would be handled would be subject to a vote of both companies.

Sometimes you are a shareholder of the company being bought. You could end up with shares of the new company, or cash, or a little of both.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous considerations as to the form of corporate M&A transactions that could fill a book.

One thing to remember, though, is that share voting control does not align perfectly with board seats. Also, in the case of non-controlling shareholders (sometimes called minority shareholders), the partnership agreement may afford the junior partner certain rights that affect how the senior partner operates the business, which may become less ideal for the senior partner as the business evolves and grows.

Gaining full control of a company requires the capital and/or financing to do so (NB: Musk had to pledge some of his shares in Tesla as collateral for the Twitter buyout financing), and some investors may find it to be a better use of their capital not to own 100% of a business or to take a non-controlling stake.

Tax reasons can sometimes figure into decisions, as well, as is commonly the case in spin-off/split-offs (at least in the U.S.).

This is only just scratching the surface of the rationale behind corporate strategic transactions, but hopefully it gives you a flavor of some of the considerations that can go into these decisions.

Answer (score -2):

In addition to control issues brought up by the other answers, there's a very simple factor. Profits, in the form of dividends, are returned to investors proportionally to their ownership/shareholding.

A owner that is pleased with their investment will want to invest more in the company and receive more returns.

If another owner wants to sell some of their shares, perhaps because they need money for other operations, this presents a good opportunity to increase ownership, even if it doesn't fundamentally change the control of the company.